# Serie of functions of complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have just started to study complex analysis, and I am doing some problems about series of functions.
Could someone how I can know if  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{e^{-nz^2}}$  ($z\in\mathbb{C}$) converges pointwise, uniformly and absolutely?

I know that the test of Weirstrass is a useful tool but I don´t know how to use it here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $z = x + iy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb R$ we have
$\lvert e^{-z^2} \rvert = e^{- \Re(z^2)} = e^{y^2 - x^2}$.
Thus we get $\lvert e ^{-nz^2} \rvert = \lvert e ^{-z^2}\rvert ^n = (e^{y^2 - x^2})^n$.

The series of absolute values is a geometric series which converges iff $e^{y^2 - x^2} < 1$. Thus the series converges absolutely iff $\lvert y \rvert < \lvert x \rvert$.

Comment: Yes, that is easy, but can we say about the other kinds os convergence?

Comment: As the other kinds of convergence all imply pointwise convergence and the geometric series converges if and only if the absolute value of the term is smaller than $1$, there is no uniform or absolute convergence when $\lvert y \rvert \geq \lvert x \rvert$.